# How to use umlaute in Icinga2 static configuration files?

Tags: icinga2, icingaweb2

I use utf-8 encoding within the Icinga2 configuration files. Everything works correctly, but the display is strange: in Icingaweb2, characters that are not part of ascii-7 are shown incorrectly.

As a specific example, the display name of a user contains an umlaut, `ä`, which is displayed as `Ã¤` in Icingaweb2.

I am using the https://github.com/jjethwa/icinga2 container to run both icinga2 and icingaweb2.

What should I do?